# Complex function representing rotation of the plane

Tags: complex-numbers

The function $f(z) = \dfrac{(-1 + i \sqrt{3}) z + (-2 \sqrt{3} - 18i)}{2}$  represents a rotation around some complex number $c$. Find $c$.

I'm not even sure what this question means. I need help.

Answer (score 1):

When a plane is rotated about some point, that point remains in place (does not move), as it's the center of rotation.

The fact of not moving (being a *fixed point*) is expressed by the equation $f(z)=z$. Solve it, and you are done.

Comment: So do I set the left side equal to 0? And then how do I solve it? I tried grouping but it didn't work.

Comment: Why would you set the left side equal to zero? The left side of what, by the way? The equation is $f(z)=z$.

Comment: Uhh f(z)? I was thinking of quadratics?

Comment: No quadratics. There is no unknown raised to a square. In my post you can see an equation; $f(z)=z$. This is the equation to be solved. Reason: $f(z)$ is where the point $z$ goes  under transformation $f$. The center of rotation stays in place: so, it satisfies the equation $f(z)=z$.

Comment: So I solve for z?

Comment: Yes. There is one solution (it's a linear equation).

Comment: So this is a linear equation with parameter z right? If I isolate z I get some fraction on the left side. Am I supposed to isolate it? Where does c come into play in this problem?

Comment: This is a linear equation with unknown $z$. To be solved for $z$. By moving everything with $z$ to one side, and everything without it to the other. The solution will be the point that is fixed by $f$. This point is what the problem calls $c$.

Comment: So 2f(z) + 2sqrt(3) + 18i = -z + zisqrt(3) ?

Comment: And by saying "The solution will be the point that is fixed by f" do you mean that we plug in the point into f(z)? Sorry ive never heard a statement like "fixed by f".

Comment: "$z$ is fixed by $f$" means that $f(z)=z$. Let me spell out this equation: $$\dfrac{(-1 + i \sqrt{3}) z + (-2 \sqrt{3} - 18i)}{2} = z$$